# Обработка форм в FastApi

Tags: python, form, jinja2, fastapi

Через шаблонизатор Jinja сделал форму. Зашел по адресу. Нажимаю отправить и выходит:

```
{"detail":[{"loc":["body","username"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}
```

Если зайти на страницу документации и отправить данные оттуда - то никаких ошибок нет и в принте можно видеть введенные данные.

Обработку POST делал по [документации](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms/)

```
@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def index(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("sign_in.html", {"request": request})

@app.post("/")
async def login(username: str = Form(), password: str = Form()):
    print('username:', username)
    print('password:', password)
    return {"username": username}
```

Что не так я сделал? Почему не могу видеть отправленные данные я через форму, размещенной на странице **sign_in.html**?

Сама форма:

```html
<form name="sign_in" id="form_0" action="/" method="post" enctype=multipart/form-data>
  <div class="input">
    <div class="blockinput">
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="e-mail">
    </div>

    <div class="blockinput">
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Пароль">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="in_submit" type="submit" value="Войти">
  </div>
</form>
```

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ:

```
@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def index(request: Request):
    print('*@app.get*')
    return templates.TemplateResponse("sign_in.html", {"request": request})

@app.post("/")
async def login(username: str = Form(), password: str = Form()):
    print('*@app.post*')
    print('username:', username)
    print('password:', password)
    return {"username": username}
```

Принты при заходе на страницу '127.0.0.1' через браузер:

```
*@app.get*
INFO:     127.0.0.1:64572 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:     127.0.0.1:64572 - "POST / HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity
INFO:     127.0.0.1:64572 - "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 405 Method Not Allowed
```

А это в браузере после отправки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Принты, при отправке данных через страницу 'http://127.0.0.1:8001/docs#/default/login__post'

```
*@app.post*
username: www@ww.ww
password: wwwwww
INFO:     127.0.0.1:64600 - "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

Comment: Вот я никогда с этим конкретным шаблонизатором не работал, но есть у меня подозрения... вот у Вас есть 2 обработчика, для get и для post. Для get - в обработчике сразу вызывается templates.TemplateResponse(). Он и приводит к отправке пользователю страницы, содержащей форму. А в post - обработчике такого нет, пользователю ничего не отправляется. Дальше - надо смотреть в консоль, работают ли "принты", прописаннеы в обработчике post

Comment: Я не уверен, что FastApi в принципе подходит для того, для чего вы его пытаетесь использовать...

Comment: @S.H., добавил дополнение в вопрос.

Comment: @andreymal, я тоже начинаю сомневаться в возможностях FastApi.... На Flask - это все решается довольно быстро и удобно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-общем, я разобрался. Оставлю решение если кто тоже будет грызть гранит в этом вопросе:

Обращаем внимание на имена в форме:

```
..
 <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="e-mail">
 <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Пароль">
..
```

В обработчике ссылок д/б те же имена:

```
@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def index(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("sign_in.html", {"request": request})


@app.post("/submitform")
async def index(email: str = Form(...), password: str = Form(...)):
    print('email:', email)
    print('password:', password)
    return RedirectResponse("/", status_code=303)
```

Вот и все. После отправки данные приходят в **/submitform**. Там можно с ними работать и потом можно редиректить (я на ту же страницу с которой отправлял).